# Download a file from a WebForm using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to download a file from a website (not written by me).
I have a valid username/password to access it, and I can do it manually.
But I want to create an automated procedure (in C#) to download it periodically.

Manually I have to login, browse to the download page, select some combo box and then click "Download".
This link performs a postback and returns the requested file.

I think I should use WebClient.DownloadFile, but I can't figure out how to pass all the necessary data and request the postback the correct way.

Comment: Your question can't be answered (the way you can use) in current form. You need to explain what type of authentication is used on the site (i.e. OAuth) and how you are getting url to the file.

Comment: The code I posted will help you download, but there is alot of data you still haven't provided.

Comment: You can use [Watin](http://watin.org/) or any other web automation API.

Comment: The website is not written by me, so I don't have an inner knowledge on how it is built. As a user, once one the download.aspx page, I click on a Link that performs the postback (__doPostBack()) and so I get the file.

Answer (score 3):

Does this other website have an API?

Otherwise, you will have to do a web request, submitting all the details in the format they require, then read the response, then automatically fill in the second form to "check  some combo box", and then finally read the response containing the file.

Alternatively, there is browser emulation software out there, such as selenium, which is used for website testing. You could setup a test/script on there which would do all the above for you. I'm not sure how that handles downloaded files though.

If you want to do route 1, be prepared to change your program each time the other website changes. And if they add a captcha, then you are pretty much screwed.

For ease, would a stored password in a web browser not save you most of the hassle??

Comment: Unfortunately not, I have to download files periodically, and it will be tens of files every time. And each file must go to a different location and receive different elaborations. I would require too much time to do manually.

Comment: Ok, IMHO, what you will need to do then is emulate a web browser. My first question would be, do you have to select different values from the combo box each time, as this will muck up your program if you do...

Comment: Unfortunately yes, I have to choose different values from combo box each time. My dream would have been requesting an Url with network credentials and all the data via querystring and having a file as a Response, but it seems it doesn't work that way. Actually a webservice would have been even more appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

You would do something like this:

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(@"http://stackoverflow.com") as HttpWebRequest;
request.Credentials = NetworkCredentials(@"username", @"password");
request.Timeout = 300;

if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(request))
     throw new Exception("Error in Request");

using(var stream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
     using(var writer = File.Create(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop))
          stream.CopyTo(writer);
```

You would use the `NetworkCredentials` to pass those to a site.  Once you create a `HttpWebRequest` you'll be able to access alot of features.

Comment: Thank you, I understand about the credentials, but I don't know how to invoke the postback. If I create the stream with the url, I'll have the html form, but I want to file. (Sorry for my english)

Comment: Side note: it is unlikely to help OP as most sites (like SO in your sample) use OAuth or form-based auth...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I was just putting a URL there.